# Stop the background from moving

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, opengl-compat

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "glut.h"
#include <math.h>

float squareX = 0.0f;
float squareY = -0.3f;
float squareZ = 0.0f;
static int flag = 1;

// The background
void drawBackground() {
    // draw the green ground
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.60, 0.0);
    glVertex2f(800, 100);
    glVertex2f(800, 0);
    glVertex2f(0, 0);
    glVertex2f(0, 100);
    glVertex2f(800, 100);
    glEnd();
    // draw the blue sky
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glVertex2f(800, 100);
    glVertex2f(800, 800);
    glVertex2f(0, 800);
    glVertex2f(0, 100);
    glVertex2f(800, 100);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}

// the hot air balloon
void drawAirBalloon(void) {
    glTranslatef(squareX, squareY, squareZ);
    // draw the balloon
    float theta;
    int cutsegment = 45;
    int start = -90 + cutsegment / 2;
    int end = 270 - cutsegment / 2;
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    for (int i = -45; i <= 225; i++) {
        theta = i * 3.142 / 180;
        glVertex2f(355 + 70 * cos(theta), 225 + 90 * sin(theta));
    }
    glEnd();
    // draw first rope on the left
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex2f(320, 95);
    glVertex2f(295, 177);
    glEnd();
    // draw first rope on the right
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex2f(415, 180);
    glVertex2f(390, 95);
    glEnd();
    // draw propane burner
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
    glVertex2f(335, 140);
    glVertex2f(335, 120);
    glVertex2f(375, 120);
    glVertex2f(375, 140);
    glVertex2f(335, 140);
    glEnd();
    // draw basket
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(0.6, 0.35, 0.1);
    glVertex2f(320, 95);
    glVertex2f(320, 40);
    glVertex2f(390, 40);
    glVertex2f(390, 95);
    glVertex2f(320, 95);
    glEnd();
}

void initRendering() {
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}

// handles the size of the screen
void handleResize(int w, int h) {
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0f, (float)w, 0.0f, (float)h, -1.0f, 1.0f);
}   

// display
void drawScene() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    // draw hot air balloon
    drawAirBalloon();
    // draw background
    drawBackground();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

// move the hot air balloon up
void update(int value) {
    if (flag) {
        squareY += 1.0f;
        if (squareY > 350.0) {
            flag = 0;
        }
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(25, update, 0);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
    glutCreateWindow("Hot Air Balloon");
    initRendering();
    glutDisplayFunc(drawScene);
    glutReshapeFunc(handleResize);
    glutTimerFunc(25, update, 0);
    glutMainLoop();
    return(0);
}
```

I am trying to create a hot air balloon to float up to the sky from the ground. I used GL_POLYGON to create the background and included it into a separate void. The hot air balloon works perfectly fine but I am having trouble stopping the background from moving. I only want the hot air balloon to go up. I want the background to stay at its position. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note, that drawing by `glBegin`/`glEnd` sequences and the fixed function pipeline matrix stack is deprecated since decades.
Read about [Fixed Function Pipeline](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fixed_Function_Pipeline) and see [Vertex Specification](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification) and [Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader) for a state of the art way of rendering.

---

The matrices on the matrix stack can be saved an restored by [`glPushMatrix` and `glPopMatrix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glPushMatrix.xml).

Use `glPushMatrix` matrix to push (save) the model view matrix before the balloon is drawn. Use `glPopMatrix` matrix  to pop (restore) the model view matrix after the balloon is drawn. This cause that the translation (`glTranslatef`) is applied to the balloon only:

```
void drawScene() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    // draw hot air balloon
    glPushMatrix();
    drawAirBalloon();
    glPopMatrix();

    // draw background
    drawBackground();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```